# GPU for Mac Book pro

Tags: mac, cinema4d, render-settings

I suffer a lot with the speed of work of my render and my computer. I have a MacBook Pro 2,9 ghz intel core i7, 32 ram, radeon pro 560 graphic card.
I want to install octane render on my computer but understood that there are quite some difficulties because of my video card that doesn’t support this render.
I wanted to buy an external graphic - nvidia GPU card to plug it in my computer to make the process faster and to be able to use a better render.
My question is - is the process safe for my MacBook Pro or will it affect it even more. Because it is overheating and making a lot of noise when it renders a project or has a lot of effects it needs to process. 
Buying a new or building a computer for this is not an option atm.
Can you help me out with an advice if this is a safe solution or is there maybe a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this will work, for several reasons.

1. You need to be on High Sierra to use CUDA. There is no support in any later macOS
2. eGPU support for MacBooks is centred around the AMD suite, basically the RXes.
3. You're trying to do workstation-grade output on a laptop.

Refs:
[EveryMac - eGPU guide](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-touch-bar-faq/what-is-an-egpu-best-external-gpu-for-macbook-pro.html)
[OctaneRender FAQs](https://home.otoy.com/render/octane-render/faqs/)

Comment: While it's possible to use an epgu with an nvidia card (I was looking into some time ago) but it's so expensive and complicated... it's cheaper/simpler to buy a separate PC